# Why Won't Event Viewer, System Information, System Configuration apps launch off the Start menu on my Windows 2016 Server on Azure?

Tags: event-viewer, sfc

It seems I cannot start Event Viewer, System Information, and System Configuration when I click the Start menu and start typing in their names to search for them; clicking their icons when they appear on the list does nothing! The Start menu just stays there!

However, while these apps won't run off the Start menu for some reason, clicking Windows + R and then typing in their executable names (eventvwr.exe, msinfo32.exe, and msconfig.exe, respectively) does work. Not sure why clicking on them off the Start menu won't.

After some research, I was led to believe there might be some corruption in Windows system files so I went to try two commands to diagnose this (per https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929833):

- DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth
- SFC /scannow

However, the DISM command failed saying, 'The source files could not be found. Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required...' Then, the SFC command above fails with the message, "Another servicing or repair operation is currently running." I thought this information might be relevant.

**UPDATE**

I was able to get my DISM and SFC commands working on this Windows Server 2016 Azure server as follows:

1. Download the Windows Server 2016 ISO file from the Microsoft Evaluation Center at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/evalcenter/evaluate-windows-server-2016?filetype=ISO
2. Mount the Windows Server 2016 ISO as a drive (with drive letter E: for example) by right-clicking on the file and selecting Mount
3. Run dism /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth
4. Run dism /online /cleanup-image /checkhealth
5. Run dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth
6. Assuming the ISO mounted on drive E:, run dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:WIM:E:\sources\install.wim:1 /limitaccess
7. Run sfc /scannow
8. Run Windows Update

The first seven steps/commands above were completed successfully and all files were repaired.

**NOTE:** Step 8 above ultimately worked, but Windows Update stalled initially, stating it was "Downloading updates". It remained at 0% for a l-o-o-o-o-ng time. It stalled while downloading files for the only current update that was pending (KB4516061). Trying to run "sfc /scannow" again to diagnose/fix my issue failed at this point (though it ran fine earlier in step 7.) It would cause Windows to complain that “Another servicing or repair operation is currently running.” That was the hung Windows Update process I presume. The issue seemed to resolve itself after several hours of churning and Windows Update now says we're up to date. The SFC command also works now and it runs successfully.

However, the issue I stated in the first paragraph continues:

> It seems I cannot start Event Viewer, System Information, and System Configuration when I click the Start menu and start typing in their names to search for them; clicking their icons when they appear on the list does nothing! The Start menu just stays there!

Is this unresponsiveness of the Windows Server 2016 Start menu by design?

Comment: I have bad news for you.  The symptoms you describe indicate severe system integrity problems.  If the commands you have tried, have not found and repaired the damage, there isn’t anything you can do at that point.  I presume the user that your logged into is the only Administrator?

Comment: I am logged in as Administrator. However, several users use this VM daily simultaneously via RDP.

Comment: System integrity appears fine now. I've cleaned up the post and tried to make it more specific to the one issue I started it with.